# does a kernel module that mounts archives as read-only directories could be good idea?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

recently I'm wondering why program installed on linux systems are just archives extracted inside system paths and not just archives mounted as read-only entry-points.

As far as I understood, Android apk files are archives that are live-mounted when the app is opened, so why there's nothing similar under other linux-based systems like desktop or server OSs?

Recently I've attended a Linux Kernel Programming course and I thought that to implement a module that automatically creates mount points with given archives could be a cool idea, but I'm guessing if anyone thought it before and why this idea could have been discarded. Personally, I did not find anything useful.

Has anyone have some information or hint on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fuse-zip`](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip/) already implements this, as a FUSE module, for ZIP files, and [`archivemount`](https://github.com/cybernoid/archivemount) exists for tarballs (or perhaps even anything supported by `libarchive`). Both of these even implement writes.

There’s nothing similar in the kernel itself, as far as I’m aware; there are related pieces of code in the kernel, *e.g.* for decompression, so implementing these in the kernel *might* not be all that complicated — but there would be some gotchas to take care of around keeping access to the archive file itself, and avoiding races. FUSE takes care of that for you.